# Porting a standalone JMS application to a web/app server

Tags: java, servlets, jms, war, spring-jms

**The Background :**

We have a JMS (point to point) based standalone application. We currently start the JMS listener in a separate JVM instance through a Java main program and we publish requests to this listener from another JVM instance through another Java main program.

**The requirement :**

We want to port only the JMS listener onto a web/application server as a war/ear. We want to start the JMS listener when the war/ear is deployed by the container.

**The questions :**

1. Would it be a good idea to write a Servlet and configure  `<load-on-startup>` as true. We can then start the JMS listener in the init method of the servlet. What are the pros and cons of doing this?
2. Is there a better option than point 1 to start the JMS listener on application startup?
3. We are using Spring and Spring JMS in our application. Can we simply move our spring context files to META-INF or is there any additional configuration changes required for the spring context files to be visible to the web app.

Note that for constraints beyond our control, we need to port the JMS listener to a web-app. I am not looking to know whether porting this is a good idea or not but rather interested in knowing how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

First, for a reference check [the JMS chapter of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html)

I am not sure I really understand what the actual issue with the web application might be: as far as Spring is concerned, this is just an application just like any other application. If you haven't done so, you should register a listener container for your your JMS listener, something like:

```
<!-- this is your message listener -->
<bean id="messageListener" class="jmsexample.ExampleListener" />

<!-- and this is the message listener container -->
<bean id="jmsContainer" 
      class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

Now you want to make sure that this listener will not consume messages unless the application has started. A typical Spring web application is defined with a root `ApplicationContext` for the core part and a child `ApplicationContext` for the servlet related parts.

By default, the container is started as part of the application context in which it has been defined. I assume that your listener does not rely on the web stuff so you should just define it in the root. There is a way to specify a **phase** to the container that is going to control **when** the application is started regarding other beans.

You can also simply set `autoStartup` to `false`. In this case, the container will not start at all and you have the freedom to start it whenever you can. For instance, you could create an `ApplicationListener` that listens for `ContextRefreshEvent` and injects your listener and start it at that time. Something like

```
public class YourListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private DefaultMessageListenerContainer container;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) { 
        this.container.start(); 
    }

    public void setContainer(DefaultMessageListnerContainer container { 
        this.container = container;
    }
}
```

Note that if you *do* rely on the web part to be available, this can be tricky to register the listener properly. Check [this answer for a full description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229077/spring-applicationlistener-for-contextrefreshevent-how-to-invoke-only-once-per/22244561#22244561) of this issue.